Hole between the leather and the non leather on my tactical boots
I am pretty sure that the stitching just came loose but I don't know how to stitch the leather back to the non leather part and I don't know what thread to use or if there is a specific way to sew it back together. The hole is just below the inside left ankle.
I use them daily as regular shoes and have had them for 6 months. As the hole is the only problem I dont want to throw them a way.

Have you been back to the shop they come from? This new they have to be under warranty. (I assume last Christmas, not next.)

Otherwise, there is almost certainly a shoe repair (known as a cobbler) or leatherworker somewhere in your local town/city who can probably repair the hole or at least advise if it is repairable.

Welcome to TGO. It should be obvious what that "hole" -- maybe "gap" is a better word? -- between the leather and non-leather is, yet your wording suggests it might not be the stiching. Can you show us a close-up photo?

It's unlikely to be stitching. Most outdoor, sports, and casual shoes have glued welts (between upper and sole, but the sole moulding can extend really quite a long way up at the back) these days, especially any that are meant to be waterproof. There are shoe-specific glues that work well

thanks for responding I will try to get some photos of the hole or gap you are all varry helpfull

No worries! That small hole is fixable. You can probably use a needle and some strong thread (nylon or upholstery thread would work well) to stitch it back up. There are tons of online tutorials that can show you a simple stitch for leather.  If you're not comfy with DIY, a cobbler could easily patch it for you too!
